# Powershell - Running .ps1 doesn't work, but running it through the console itself does

Tags: windows, powershell

Before I start, please note I am a beginner at Powershell, so some questions I ask may seem very obvious and stupid to the more experienced.

I have a problem with my script. If I copy paste it into Powershell itself, it works with no problems. However putting it in a .ps1 file, and making it execute with Powershell doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why, and what I can do to make it work using a .ps1? Here's the code:

```
$Group = import-csv -path C:\Output\Gruppe.csv
$DomainUsers = import-csv -path C:\Output\DomainUsers.csv
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
Get-ADGroupMember –identity Test –recursive | select "samaccountname" | Export-csv –path C:\Output\Gruppe.csv -NoTypeInformation
Get-ADUser –Filter * -SearchBase ”ou=Domain Users,dc=sfol,dc=local” | select "samaccountname" | Export-csv –path C:\Output\DomainUsers.csv –NoTypeInformation
Compare-Object $Group $DomainUsers -property samaccountname -IncludeEqual | where-object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="} | select "samaccountname" | Export-csv C:\Output\Difference.csv –NoTypeInformation 
(Get-Content C:\Output\Difference.csv) | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file -FilePath C:\Output\Difference.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
$File = "C:\Output\Difference.csv"
$Time = Get-Date
ForEach ($User in (Get-Content $File))
{   Try {
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Test" -Member $User -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
        Add-Content c:\Output\Gruppelog.log -Value "$Time - $User slettet fra gruppen"
    }
    Catch {
        Add-Content c:\Output\Gruppelog.log -Value "$Time - $User medlem kunne ikke blive slettet fra gruppen pga: $($Error[0])"
    }
}
```

I also have another problem I noticed as I am writing this question. What this script does is to print out a userlist from an OU and a group. Then it compares the OU to the group using the two files it printed out, and prints out a new userlist containing only the users that exists in both the OU and the group. Then it uses the new userlist to remove users from the group (so that there is no users that exist in both the OU and group).

This script works well the first time I run it, but if I proceed with re-adding the users to the group, running the script again, sometimes it will only remove some of the users. If I do ctrl+c and CLS after running the script, it works fine. As mentioned, I am a beginner at this, so I'd just like to know why it doesn't work 100% the second time without ctrl+c or cls. Sorry if I am bad at explaining, and I don't expect you to help me with this since it's not a part of the question. But I'd appreciate it if you could.

Kind regards, Shadow

Comment: you may have a problem with the execution policy, try `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in your console, then the scriptfile should run as expected. see http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee176961.aspx

Comment: Thanks Gruntzy, I already did that, so maybe this will help someone else with a similar problem. However, in the meantime I found that it was because the ActiveDirectory module apparently isn't permanently added when you do `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`. I thought it did. Adding `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` in the beginning of the code fixed the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was not having imported the module ActiveDirectory. I thought that when you imported the module once, it would stay for future use in Powershell. This isn't so, so what I did to fix the problem was adding `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` to the beginning of the code. I still haven't figured out my bonus question, so if anyone can help with that, it'd be great.